# Contact forces and the structure of matter

Tags: forces, matter

Textbooks on introductory physics depict friction force as a result of interatomic forces. Matter is made of atoms and those atoms have eletric bounds. In turn, those eletric bounds are responsible for the friction force at macroscopic level.

In a very simplified view, if one could zoom in to the molecular level of a book sitting still on a table, oen could see that the book "sinks" on the table. That simplified picture is used to describe the origin of the contact forces.

Question: Has that molecular picture actually been captured and measured? Or is that too small to actually see it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the molecular picture has been actually extensively researched theoretically, simulated, and experimentally investigated!

The term you might be looking for is [nanotribology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanotribology). There have been several atomic-level studies of friction, there is a nice Scientific American [article](http://www.physics.ncsu.edu/nanotribology/publications/ref58.pdf) available as well. The latter article explains several experimental approaches to the problem with illustrations. There is even a book on the subject (*Sliding Friction: Physical Principles and Applications* by Bo N. J. Persson) , which has a chapter dedicated to experimental methods.